# Error Connecting to Apple ID Server Recovery Assistant

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id, password, recovery

I just opened my mac after about 6-7 months and I am unable to login to my user accounts. I am not sure why my password isn't working. I can't think of any instance if I changed it. Two accounts and can't login to both of them.

But, now I want to reset my password. Upon clicking the ? button, it shows that i can reset it using apple id, I click on it. System restarts and recovery assistant is opened.

Asks for my apple id and password and it isn't working as well. giving me an error that "There was an error connecting to Apple ID Server". I have a stable internet connection (with which I am posting this) and it shows connected as well on recovery assistant screen. Clicking on "Forgot Apple ID or password?" link, it says, "You currently have no internet connection"

Totally not getting what's happening!

Comment: Are you using WiFi or Ethernet?  Do you have “Limit IP tracking” enabled?

Comment: @Allan using WiFi, and I don't remember enabling that option